# reload data uitableview from another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I want to reload data of `UITableview` from another `UIView`.

(the `UITableview` is in `ListNoteViewController`)

the call I do from `DetailViewController` (the other uiview) is :

```
ListNoteViewController *controller = [[ListNoteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListNoteViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[controller.TableNotes reloadData];
```

but nothing happens. Please, someone can help me ?

Advanced thanks

Comment: you can use Custom delegate to achieve this

Comment: See my answer.Hope the concept is clear from it and feel free to ask if you have more doubts

Answer (score 3):

Nothing will happen, because you are trying to reload a tableview which is **not yet created!**
The UI elements like `UITableView`, `UILabel` etc will be created only after the view of the particular UIViewController is loaded. Here you have just initialised the viewcontroller only.

So you should write this in

```
     -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
     {
        [self.TableNotes reloadData];
     }
```

OR

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
   {
       [self.TableNotes reloadData];
   }
```

of your ListNoteViewController.

This is the problem with your code. And in case, if the `ListNoteViewController` is already in stack,ie, if you have already loaded the same viewcontroller and is now trying to reload the tableview on it,  then you can use **custom delegates** to achieve the same.

you can see [how to add a delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626946/1756131) here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use delegates.

in DetailViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id Delegate;
```

In ListNoteViewController.m

```
-(void)myTVReloadMethod {
[myTable reloadData];
}
```

And when you are going to DetailViewController

```
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
dvc.Delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated: yes];
```

In any method in DetailViewController

```
[delegate performSelector:@selector(myTVReloadMethod) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Hi. I am using MFSideMenu. I am not able to pass data to menuViewController. This contains list in tableview, because menuviewcontroller already loaded and tableview called before login details.